# How to use HTTPS in Delphi 10.3 with INDY

Tags: delphi, ssl, post, https

Hi everybody and all Programmers out there,

at the moment I want to figure out, how to use a HTTPS request (POST) with Delphi.
I have this piece of code:

```
uses ..., IdHTTP, IdSSLOpenSSL;

....

procedure TForm2.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  PostStrings    :TStringList;
  ResponseStream :TStringStream;
  ausgabe        :String;
  zeile          :String;
  i              :Integer;
  s              :array of string;
  Strings        :TStringList;
  Stream         :TStringStream;

begin
  Stream  := TStringStream.Create('');
  Strings := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Strings.Add('Noone='+Edit1.Text);
    Strings.Add('Foo='+Edit2.Text);

    IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);

    try
      IdHTTP1.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP1);
      IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;
      idHTTP1.Post('https://api.mysitefortest.de/postit.php', Strings,stream);
      ausgabe := Stream.DataString; 
      zeile := ''; 

      for i:=1 to Length(ausgabe) do begin
        if (ausgabe[i]=#13) and (ausgabe[i+1]=#10) then begin
          ResponseMemo.Lines.Add(zeile);
          zeile:='';
        end else if s[i]<>#10 Then zeile:=zeile+ausgabe[i];
      end;
      ResponseMemo.Lines.Add(zeile);
    except 
     on E: Exception do
       showmessage('Error encountered during POST: ' + E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    Strings.Free;
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The php file:

```
<?php
echo 'Noone: '.$zitatArray["Noone"]; 
echo Chr(13).Chr(10); 
echo 'Foo: '.$zitatArray["Foo"];

?>
```

The error comes up, if I press the sendpost button. It says, the ssl.-library cant be loaded.

MMhhh - it seems a secret how to use ssl with indy. I've searched google but I don't find some clear example.
I think I need a library for the ssl. But which one? How to use it in my Delphi? Where to get it?

Hope someone can help and explain it - also for other programmers to solve this issue??

Thanks

(sorry if my code is not clear - I´m still learning ;))

Comment: It seems that you aren't able to find the SSL libraries. Are you using OpenSSL? You may need to install it. I recommend https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Comment: "*it seems a secret how to use ssl with indy.*" - see [Securing Indy Network Connections](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Securing_Indy_Network_Connections) in Embarcadero's documentation. OpenSSL 1.0.2 and earlier DLLs that are known to work with Indy are available at https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries. Indy has [experimental support for OpenSSL 1.1.x](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pull/299), but you will have to obtain those DLLs elsewhere.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: thanks for the answers.

Comment: found something here https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/Archive/Experimental/ and this is what I needed. Put the two .dll's into the directory and the app is still running.

Comment: but - I wonder how other developers contribute there app? The dll's must be also contributed. Is this legal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you might not have an SSL library installed.
Using OpenSSL (installation here https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)

Here is an example of using Indy 10 to POST a body with headers using SSL/TLS 1.2

To set up the connection

```
uses
      SysUtils, Classes, uTAuthToken, IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerSocket, IdIOHandlerStack,
      IdSSL,IdSSLOpenSSL, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient,
      IdIntercept, IdHTTP, IdCoder, IdCoder3to4, IdCoderMIME;

var
    fIdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
    fIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;

  fIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  with fIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions do begin
   Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
   Mode   := sslmClient;
   SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];
  end;
  fIdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  if aConnectTimeout>100 then
   fIdHTTP.ConnectTimeout := aConnectTimeout;
  if aReadTimeout>100 then
   fIdHTTP.ReadTimeout := aReadTimeout;
  fIdHTTP.IOHandler := fIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  if aProxyServer<>'' then begin
   with fIdHTTP.ProxyParams do begin
    ProxyServer := aProxyServer;
    ProxyPort   := aProxyPort;
   end;
  end;
```

To post a body with an authroization header

```
  aResponse := '';
  aError    := '';
  aParams := TStringStream.create(aMessage);
  try
   with fIdHTTP do begin
    Request.Clear;
    Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
    Request.CustomHeaders.Add(Format('Authorization: Bearer %s',[access_token]));
    Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
    Response.KeepAlive := False;
    aResponse := Post(aUri, aParams);
    aResponse := aResp;
   end;
  finally
   aParams.Free;
  end;
```

HTH

Comment: the magic for me was this:     
`
IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);

    try

    {
      IdHTTP1.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP1);
      IdHTTP1.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
      IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;
    }
      IdHTTP1.AllowCookies := True;
      SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP1);
      SSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
      IdHTTP1.IOHandler := SSL;
`